# Arquivos de leitura em ASCII do Censo Demografico 2010

Tags: r, ascii, sas

Alguem sabe onde baixar os arquivos ASCII (.sas) para leitura dos microdados do Censo Demografico 2010 do IBGE ?

Sei que o [Anthony Damico](https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/Censo%20Demografico) mantem apenas alguns arquivos no site dele (veja abaixo como fazer o download), mas estou procurando os arquivos disponibilizados pelo proprio IBGE. O Damico nao disponibiliza, por exemplo, o arquivo de leitura da base de mortalidade.

```
   # download arquivo SAS de pessoas

     download.file( "https://raw.github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/master/Censo%20Demografico/SASinputPes.txt" , "LEPESSOAS.sas" )
```

ps. No [site do IBGE/censo 2010](http://www.ibge.gov.br/home/estatistica/populacao/censo2010/resultados_gerais_amostra/resultados_gerais_amostra_tab_uf_microdados.shtm) e possivel fazer o download dos microdados e documentacao, mas nao ha nenhuma informacao sobre os arquivos de leitura em SAS

## UPDATE (02 Out 2015)

Confirmei a resposta do @Rcoster com dois pesquisadores do IBGE. O IBGE nao disponibiliza no site os arquivos de leitura de SAS.
Segui a sugestao de @Rcoster e criei um script que:

- faz download dos dados e da documentacao do censo 2010
- usa o dicionario de variveis em excel para construir o arquivo de leitura da base em `.txt` e converter para formato `data.table`
- salva as bases em `.csv`

[O script eh bem rapido e esta disponivel aqui](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/Brazilian_Census_2010). Sugestoes sao bem vindas.

Comment: Os microdados do censo estão em CSV ou .xls, portanto a leitura é feita de maneira direta (`read.xsl()` ou `read.csv2()`). Ou tu quer dos dados da amostra?

Comment: Eu quero ler os dados da amostra. Obrigado pela informacao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @Rcoster, apresento aqui uma solucao alternativa em que se controi a sintaxe de leitura dos dados `.txt` a partir do arquivo dicionario de variaveis `.xls`.

```
# Load libraries
  library(data.table)
  library(readxl)


# Abre arquivo Excel com dicionario de variaveis
  dic_dom <- read_excel("./Documentacao/Layout_microdados_Amostra.xls", sheet =1, skip = 1)
  dic_pes <- read_excel("./Documentacao/Layout_microdados_Amostra.xls", sheet =2, skip = 1)
  dic_mor <- read_excel("./Documentacao/Layout_microdados_Amostra.xls", sheet =4, skip = 1)

# converte para data.table
  setDT(dic_dom)
  setDT(dic_pes)
  setDT(dic_mor)

# Cria funcao para computar largura das variaveis, e muda nome de posicao inicial e final
  computeWidth <- function(dataset){dataset[is.na(DEC), DEC := 0]
                                    dataset[, width := INT + DEC]
                                    setnames(dataset,colnames(dataset)[3],"pos.ini")
                                    setnames(dataset,colnames(dataset)[4],"pos.fin")
                                    }



# Aplica funcao
  lapply(list(dic_dom,dic_pes,dic_mor), computeWidth)
```

[Esse codigo foi tirado desse scritp aqui, que faz o download e a leitura das bases do censo demografico 2010](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/Brazilian_Census_2010)

Answer (score 2):

Esses arquivos não são disponibilizados pelo IBGE. O que o IBGE disponibiliza é [um arquivo com layout de cada um dos bancos](ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/Documentacao.zip) (Layout / Layout_microdados_Amostra.xls), o que permite que tu faça a tua própria sintaxe.